# RxWorker being called multiple times even when not scheduled?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-workmanager

I have followed [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/injecting-into-workers-android-workmanager-and-dagger-948193c17684) article on how to do DI on WorkManagers, so I have this factory:

```
 class MyWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(
        val workerFactories: Map<Class<out ListenableWorker>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ChildWorkerFactory>>
) : WorkerFactory() {

    override fun createWorker(
            appContext: Context,
            workerClassName: String,
            workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker? {

        val foundEntry = workerFactories.entries.find { Class.forName(workerClassName).isAssignableFrom(it.key) }

        return if (foundEntry != null) {
            val factoryProvider = foundEntry.value
            factoryProvider.get().create(appContext, workerParameters)
        } else {
            val workerClass = Class.forName(workerClassName).asSubclass(ListenableWorker::class.java)
            val constructor = workerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Context::class.java, WorkerParameters::class.java)
            constructor.newInstance(appContext, workerParameters)
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my module:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class WorkerKey(val value: KClass<out ListenableWorker>)


@Module
abstract class ParcelPollModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @WorkerKey(ParcelPollWorker::class)
    internal abstract fun bindMyWorkerFactory(worker: ParcelPollWorker.Factory): ChildWorkerFactory


}
```

Which is part of my Application Component. Then on my Application class I do this:

```
@Inject lateinit var myWorkerFactory: MyWorkerFactory

private fun setupWorkerFactory() {
        WorkManager.initialize(
                this,
                Configuration.Builder()
                        .setWorkerFactory(myWorkerFactory)
                        .build()
        )
    }
```

My Worker class:

```
class ParcelPollWorker constructor(val parcelRepository: LocalParcelRepository,
                                   val correosRepository: CorreosRepository,
                                   appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : RxWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        Timber.w("Parcel poll worker $this here trying to do some work!")
        return parcelRepository.getParcels()
                .flatMapIterable {
                    it
                }

                .map {
                    Timber.d("Parcel poll checking parcel with code ${it.code}")
//                    correosRepository.getParcelStatus(it.code)
                }
                .toList()
                .map { Result.success() }
                .onErrorReturn {
                    Result.failure()
                }

    }


    class Factory @Inject constructor(
            val myRepository: LocalParcelRepository,
            val networkService: CorreosRepository
    ) : ChildWorkerFactory {

        override fun create(appContext: Context, params: WorkerParameters): ListenableWorker {
            return ParcelPollWorker(myRepository, networkService, appContext, params)
        }
    }


}
```

Now even if I dont schedule this worker *at all*, my log is printing `Parcel poll worker $this here trying to do some work!` with different instances multiple times (sometimes 3, sometimes 6)! Also the lines of the actual work get printed multiple times on startup of the app:

```
2020-01-08 08:37:40.892 7011-7011/com.myapp.android W/ParcelPollWorker: Parcel poll worker com.myapp.service.worker.ParcelPollWorker@c1f5d23 here trying to do some work!
2020-01-08 08:37:40.923 7011-7011/com.myapp.android W/ParcelPollWorker: Parcel poll worker com.myapp.service.worker.ParcelPollWorker@c80a87f here trying to do some work!
2020-01-08 08:37:40.924 7011-7011/com.myapp.android W/ParcelPollWorker: Parcel poll worker com.myapp.service.worker.ParcelPollWorker@85b9895 here trying to do some work!
2020-01-08 08:37:40.945 7011-7113/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 63583511008898301184149
2020-01-08 08:37:40.946 7011-7113/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 800692129
2020-01-08 08:37:40.946 7011-7113/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code PQ5HG70200028570115706M
2020-01-08 08:37:40.946 7011-7113/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code UX6CFH0459568380108027M
2020-01-08 08:37:40.947 7011-7113/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 6307253297994985
2020-01-08 08:37:40.949 7011-7113/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 63583560022440001250051
2020-01-08 08:37:40.954 7011-7102/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 63583511008898301184149
2020-01-08 08:37:40.955 7011-7102/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 800692129
2020-01-08 08:37:40.955 7011-7102/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code PQ5HG70200028570115706M
2020-01-08 08:37:40.955 7011-7101/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 63583511008898301184149
2020-01-08 08:37:40.955 7011-7101/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 800692129
2020-01-08 08:37:40.955 7011-7102/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code UX6CFH0459568380108027M
2020-01-08 08:37:40.955 7011-7101/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code PQ5HG70200028570115706M
2020-01-08 08:37:40.956 7011-7101/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code UX6CFH0459568380108027M
2020-01-08 08:37:40.956 7011-7102/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 6307253297994985
2020-01-08 08:37:40.956 7011-7102/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 63583560022440001250051
2020-01-08 08:37:40.956 7011-7101/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 6307253297994985
2020-01-08 08:37:40.956 7011-7101/com.myapp.android D/ParcelPollWorker$createWork: Parcel poll checking parcel with code 63583560022440001250051
```

How is this even possible? I checked the implementation of RxWorker and it shouldn print at least the work itself until its started (i.e. someone subscribes to it)

```
public RxWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(appContext, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
    mSingleFutureObserverAdapter = new SingleFutureAdapter<>();

    final Scheduler scheduler = getBackgroundScheduler();
    createWork()
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            // observe on WM's private thread
            .observeOn(Schedulers.from(getTaskExecutor().getBackgroundExecutor()))
            .subscribe(mSingleFutureObserverAdapter);
    return mSingleFutureObserverAdapter.mFuture;
}
```

I'm lost here on what could be happening. Code is open source and can be checked [here](https://github.com/kelmer44/correos-tracker/tree/feature/workmanager)

Class holding the worker:

```
class ParcelListActivity : BaseActivity() {


    @Inject
    lateinit var myWorkerFactory: MyWorkerFactory


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            startActivityForResult(CreateActivity.newIntent(this),
                    REQ_CREATE_PARCEL)
        }

        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()


        val uploadWorker = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                ParcelPollWorker::class.java, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(uploadWorker)
    }

...

}
```

Changes after @art suggestions:

```
private fun initWorker() {
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()


        val uploadWorker = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                ParcelPollWorker::class.java, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).cancelAllWork()
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(PARCEL_CHECKER_WORKREQUEST, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, uploadWorker)

    }
```

Comment: How are you scheduling this?

Comment: I am not, thats the thing that weirds me out the most

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on those log lines and see what is creating the worker. I suspect the framework auto-starts them for you.

Comment: *checked the implementation of RxWorker and it shouldn print at least the work itself until its started (i.e. someone subscribes to it)*. This is not right, the executions starts just when RxJava subscribe gets called.

Comment: Add the code how you launch your worker. Depending on how you launch WorkManager can persist tasks into database and then query tasks from db and execute work. It can be possible that you have launched your workers several times.

Comment: Sadly I'm not in the computer for a while now but you can check the ParcelListActivity on the repo I linked (project is open source). The Worker is created though a factory which is injected via Dagger2

Comment: @art I just put that piece of the code

Comment: @GabrielSanmartin As I said WorkManager can persist enqueued work into database and it does this exactly for periodic workers. Presumably you enqueued periodic worker at some moment of your development process (probably you enqueued the work three times), and even you have removed enqueuing code later, the periodic worker has already been persisted into db and it is launched at app startup.

Comment: but why is it triggering the job already? I can understand it creating multiple instances, but the job should only run when startwork is executed right? Then why is it executing it 3 times simultaneously? Jobs can be created but they should be executed when they are scheduled right?

Comment: Multiple instances of the worker have been scheduled. Then each of them is exectued at some moment. Do you remember what exact work request configuration you had earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Note that according to the source code of `RxWorker`:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
    mSingleFutureObserverAdapter = new SingleFutureAdapter<>();

    final Scheduler scheduler = getBackgroundScheduler();
    createWork()
        .subscribeOn(scheduler)
        // observe on WM's private thread
        .observeOn(Schedulers.from(getTaskExecutor().getBackgroundExecutor()))
        .subscribe(mSingleFutureObserverAdapter);
    return mSingleFutureObserverAdapter.mFuture;
}
```

the execution of the work starts at the moment when `subscribe` method of `Single` object get called. So your statement is not correct:

> How is this even possible? I checked the implementation of RxWorker and it shouldn print at least the work itself until its started (i.e. someone subscribes to it)

**2.** Presumably during your development process at some moment you had worker enqueuing code in `ParcelListActivity.onCreate` method and you opened this activity several times and hence enqueued periodic worker several times, `WorkManager` persisted this work into its internal database and now the work is launched according to your preiod request configuration.

To fix this you can use [cancelAllWork](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#cancelAllWork()) method. But as docs claims you this method should be used with extreme caution! Generally more accurate handling is required for periodic work. For example you can [assign a tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder.html#addTag(java.lang.String)) for your work request and then you can use [cancelAllWorkByTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#cancelAllWorkByTag(java.lang.String)) method to cancel work. Moreover you can consider to [launch your work as unique](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest)) - it is more suitable approach for most of cases.

Comment: I just did this, but I cant prevent the code being executed constantly, its neverending! I appended my code to the original post. Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you have in logs? Additionally you can override [`onStopped`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.html#onStopped()) to add logging here too.

Comment: It was a result of me using a Room Flowable and pushing again to the DB within the scheduled code. Now it works beautifully, thanks!